How to map NetSuite Item IDs to Salesforce Product IDs in User Event Script?
I've created a User Event Script to sync NetSuite Sales Orders to Salesforce. The script successfully posts the sales order body details to Salesforce orders. Now, I'm trying to post the sales order item details to Salesforce order products. To do this, I need to map the NetSuite item IDs to Salesforce product IDs, but these IDs are different in each system.
How can I map the NetSuite item ID to the corresponding Salesforce product ID?
Here is my User Event Script:
function afterSubmit(context) {
    var accessToken = 'hsbhavcghvdhgvh';
    log.debug("Access Token", accessToken);
    if (!accessToken) {
        throw new Error('Failed to get access token from Salesforce');
    }

    var rec = context.newRecord;
    var orderId = rec.id;
    var orderNo = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'tranid' });
    var memo = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'memo' });
    var total = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'total' });
    var billCity = 'San Jose';
    var billZip = '95020';
    var billState = "CA";
    var billCountry = 'US';

    var accountName = '001dM00000HNyOHQA1';
    var today = new Date();
    var orderStartDate = '2025-10-15';  // Correct date format YYYY-MM-DD
    var contractNumber = '800dM00000FjAhDQAV';
    var status = 'Draft';
    var description = memo;

    var pbid = getPriceBookId(accessToken);
    //log.debug("pbid",pbid);
    var priceBookId=pbid.records[0].Id;
    log.debug("priceBookId",priceBookId);

    var soData = {
        Name: orderNo,
        AccountId: accountName,
        EffectiveDate: orderStartDate,
        ContractId: contractNumber,
        Status: status,
        Description: description,
        BillingCity: billCity,
        BillingState: billState,
        BillingPostalCode: billZip,
        BillingCountry: billCountry,
        Pricebook2Id:priceBookId

    };

    try {
        if (context.type === context.UserEventType.CREATE) {
            log.debug("inside create");
            // Create order in Salesforce
            var createResponse = createSalesforceOrder(accessToken, soData);
            log.debug("Salesforce Create Response", createResponse);
            if (createResponse.success) {
                // Update the custom field with Salesforce ID
                var salesforceId = createResponse.id;
                record.submitFields({
                    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    id: orderId,
                    values: {
                        'custbody_salesforce_order_id': salesforceId 
                    }
                });

                // Create order items in Salesforce
                createSalesforceOrderItems(rec, accessToken, salesforceId);

            } else {
                throw new Error('Failed to create order in Salesforce: ' + JSON.stringify(createResponse.error));
            }
        } else if (context.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
            var salesforceId = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'custbody_salesforce_order_id' });  // Retrieve existing Salesforce ID
            if (salesforceId) {

                var updateBody = {
                    City__c : "Pune"
                }
                log.debug("updateBody",updateBody);

                // Update existing order in Salesforce
                var updateResponse = updateSalesforceOrder(accessToken, updateBody, salesforceId);
                log.debug("Salesforce Update Response", updateResponse);
                if (!updateResponse.success) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to update order in Salesforce: ' + JSON.stringify(updateResponse.error));
                }
            } else {
                log.error('No Salesforce ID found for update', 'Cannot update order without Salesforce ID.');
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        log.error('Error processing order', e.message);
    }
}


function createSalesforceOrder(accessToken, soData) {
    var response = https.post({
        url: 'https://abcd-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/Order/',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(soData)
    });

    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
    if (response.code === 201) {
        return {
            success: true,
            id: responseBody.id
        };
    } else {
        log.error('Error creating order in Salesforce', responseBody);
        return {
            success: false,
            error: responseBody
        };
    }
}

function updateSalesforceOrder(accessToken, updateData, salesforceId) {
    log.debug("updateData", updateData);
    log.debug("salesforceId", salesforceId);
    var response = https.post({
        url: 'https://abcd-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/Order/' + salesforceId + '?_HttpMethod=PATCH',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updateData)
    });

    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
    log.debug("response--->", response);
    if (response.code === 204) {
        return {
            success: true
        };
    } else {
        log.error('Error updating order in Salesforce', responseBody);
        return {
            success: false,
            error: responseBody
        };
    }
}

function createSalesforceOrderItems(rec, accessToken, salesforceOrderId) {
    var itemCount = rec.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        var itemId = rec.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            line: i
        });
        var quantity = rec.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'quantity',
            line: i
        });
        var rate = rec.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'rate',
            line: i
        });
        var amount = rec.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'amount',
            line: i
        });

       
        var priceBookProductId = getpriceBookProductId(accessToken,salesforceProductId);
        log.debug("priceBookProductId-->",priceBookProductId);
        var pbpid=priceBookProductId.records[0].Id;
        log.debug("pbpid",pbpid);
       
        if (salesforceProductId) {
            var orderItemData = {
                OrderId: salesforceOrderId,
                Product2Id: salesforceProductId, //(Need to access saleforce product id here)
                Quantity: quantity,
                UnitPrice: rate,
                //TotalPrice: amount,
                PricebookEntryId:pbpid
            };
            log.debug("orderItemData-->",orderItemData);

            var response = https.post({
                url: 'https://abcd-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/OrderItem/',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(orderItemData)
            });

            var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
            if (response.code === 201) {
                log.debug('Salesforce Order Item Created', responseBody.id);
            } else {
                log.error('Error creating order item in Salesforce', responseBody);
            }
        } else {
            log.error('Salesforce Product ID not found', 'Cannot create order item without Salesforce Product ID.');
        }
    }
}


function getPriceBookId(accessToken) {
    var response = https.get({
        url: 'https://abcd-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+Name+FROM+Pricebook2+WHERE+Name+LIKE+%27Standard+Price+Book%27',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });

    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
    log.debug("accountDetails", responseBody);
    if (response.code === 200) {
        return responseBody;
    } else {
        log.error('Error getting account details from Salesforce', responseBody);
        return null;
    }
}

function getpriceBookProductId(accessToken, sfProductId) {
    var sfpid = '01tdM000005c9aWQAQ';
    var response = https.get({
        url: "https://abcd-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+PricebookEntry+WHERE+Pricebook2.Name+LIKE+'Standard+Price+Book'+AND+Product2Id='" + sfpid + "'",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });

    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
    log.debug("accountDetails", responseBody);
    if (response.code === 200) {
        return responseBody;
    } else {
        log.error('Error getting account details from Salesforce', responseBody);
        return null;
    }
}

